# Check if user input a blank c++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I need to make a loop that gets three strings as input from a user and stop if nothing is entered.
My code

```
while(true){
cout << "Enter string1 string2 string3: ";
getline(cin,s1, ' ');
if(s1.empty())
    break;
getline(cin, s2, ' ');
getline(cin, s3);
}
```

If I don't enter anything, getline waits until I input at least a space. How to make it stop when nothing is entered?

Comment: `if(s1.empy())` -> `if(s1.empty())`

Comment: Show us a [MCVE] and explain how it doesn't work  please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

1. Read a line of text.
2. Use the line to construct a `istringstream`. Use the `istringstream` to extract the variables.

Here's what I am thinking:

```
std::string line;
while ( getline(std::cin, line) )
{
   std::istringstream str(line);
   if ( !(str >> s1 >> s2 >> s3 ) )
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same idea, didn't know how to implement in right.